# Why the eigenvalue calculated by Java (JAMA/math3) and Matlab/Python are different?

Tags: java, matlab, eigenvalue

There are some needs to calculate the eigenvalues of a given matrix, but I found different results are given in Matlab and Java.
**Given a Matrix in Matlab**:

```
 x=[[0.9991064766057767, 1.3003274547457159E8, 8.2589524321425552E16,9.065301406782726E25, 3.1791759769979634E34, 5.145828201380777E42];[5.905543519041531E-4,6.52297956260086E7,1.1242553048989866E16,2.9885609033349647E24,8.710071169857434E32,4.288190167817314E41];[1.8659562881188536E-4,2095424.7256421563,9.512929502991425E14,1.6603116129638694E23,0,0];[1.0062771059108464E-4, 271629.131101761, 8.648117729992205E13, 0, 0, 0];[1.3392896733345797E-5,38804.161585965856,0,0,0,0]; [2.3528061828850723E-6,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

**Output V matrix (use function eigs()):**

```
   0.9993 + 0.0000i   0.9993 + 0.0000i  -0.9987 + 0.0000i  -0.9987 + 0.0000i   0.9998 + 0.0000i   0.9998 + 0.0000i
   0.0387 + 0.0000i   0.0387 + 0.0000i  -0.0509 + 0.0000i  -0.0510 + 0.0000i  -0.0211 + 0.0000i  -0.0211 - 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0077 + 0.0000i   0.0077 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 - 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 - 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
```

**D matrix:**
1.0e+18 *

```
   7.7371 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i  -7.7371 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   3.7897 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i  -3.7888 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 3.7358i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 - 3.7358i
```

while in JAVA:
define the same test matrix:

```
    double[][] test = new double[6][6];
    test[0][0] = 0.9991064766057767;
    test[0][1] = 1.3003274547457159E8;
    test[0][2] = 8.2589524321425552E16;
    test[0][3] = 9.065301406782726E25;
    test[0][4] = 3.1791759769979634E34;
    test[0][5] = 5.145828201380777E42;
    test[1][0] = 5.905543519041531E-4;
    test[1][1] = 6.52297956260086E7;
    test[1][2] = 1.1242553048989866E16;
    test[1][3] = 2.9885609033349647E24;
    test[1][4] = 8.710071169857434E32;
    test[1][5] = 4.288190167817314E41;
    test[2][0] = 1.8659562881188536E-4;
    test[2][1] = 2095424.7256421563;
    test[2][2] = 9.512929502991425E14;
    test[2][3] = 1.6603116129638694E23;
    test[3][0] = 1.0062771059108464E-4;
    test[3][1] = 271629.131101761;
    test[3][2] = 8.648117729992205E13;
    test[4][0] = 1.3392896733345797E-5;
    test[4][1] = 38804.161585965856;
    test[5][0] = 2.3528061828850723E-6;
    RealMatrix matrix = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(test);
    EigenDecomposition eigen = new EigenDecomposition(matrix);
```

I get D matrix:

```
Array2DRowRealMatrix{{-151115727451828650000000.0,151115727451828650000000.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0},{-151115727451828650000000.0,-151115727451828650000000.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0},{0.0,0.0,121490934714923220000000.0,835322221745495900000000.0,0.0,0.0},{0.0,0.0,-835322221745495900000000.0,121490934714923220000000.0,0.0,0.0},{0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,-24594465620584907000000.0,24594465620584907000000.0},{0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,-24594465620584907000000.0,-24594465620584907000000.0}}
```

Why the results are greatly different (one is in the level of E18, while the other one is in the level of E23)?
I tried Python, they output the same results as those in Matlab.

When I tried some matrix with Integer numbers, JAVA and Matlab can output the same results.

Is there anything I did uncorrectly?

Comment: You have numbers in your input matrix that differ by 40 orders of magnitude. You really should be reading up on floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: Thank you. I also found that the issue seems to be caused by the order of magnitude. Do you have any idea about how to calculate such numbers? Since the data I used cannot be changed....

Comment: It depends on what you need to accomplish. Your numbers in MATLAB are likely correct, but you’d get the same result, I think, if you replaced all the tiny numbers by zeros. The Java output is not even complex, which leads me to believe that the library you use there doesn’t know about complex eigenvalues, and doesn’t know to raise an error when the matrix has no real-valued eigenvalues. So it gives bogus numbers. What library do you use there? (I know nothing of Java, so don’t know if this is built in or not).

Comment: I tried both JAMA and math3 libraries, which output the same (wrong) results...